# two function with same functionality return different value because i haven't use "return" keyword inside one function exact before function call

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, return, return-value

I wrote a function that flatten and array.

```
  const multiArray = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5]]], 6, [7, 8, 9, [10]]]

  let newArray = []
  const flatenArray = (params) => {
    params.map((sm) => {
      if(Array.isArray(sm)) {
        return flatenArray(sm)
      }
      newArray.push(sm);
    })
    return newArray
  }

  //console.log(flatenArray(multiArray)) result [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The above function works fine.

but if I remove the return keyword from the "if" block then does it returns something else?

```
let newArray2 = []
  const flatenArray2 = (params) => {
    params.map((sm) => {
      if(Array.isArray(sm)) {
        flatenArray(sm)
      }
      newArray2.push(sm);
    })
    return newArray2
  }

  console.log(flatenArray2(multiArray)) 
  //result [1,[2,3,[4,[5]]],6,[7,8,9,[10]]]
```

Now I would like to know...

**Why should I use the return keyword there even when I'm calling it?**

**What is happening when I use the return keyword there?**

Comment: You are showing the same code twice. The only difference is `flatenArray` vs `flatenArray2`. What `return` are you talking about?

Comment: This probably should be `if (Array.isArray(sm)) { flatenArray(sm) } else { newArray.push(sm); }` - you're missing the `else` keyword! (Or you can achieve the same with an early `return`)

Comment: code is updated now. can you check now @Ivar

Comment: code is updated now. can you check now @Bergi

Comment: As I suspected, you should be using `else` in there, which has the same effect as that `return`. Also notice that `flatenArray2` does the recursive call to `flatenArray(sm)`, but should do `flatenArray2(sm)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is happening when I use the `return` keyword there?

The function (the callback that you're passing to `map`) does return a value and stop executing. This means it will not reach the next line, `newArray.push(sm);`, after the `if` statement, which does push the `sm` array onto the result array in your second implementation.

> Why should I use the `return` keyword there even when I'm calling it?

You shouldn't actually. Using an `else` statement would be much cleaner (and also [you shouldn't abuse `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/)):

```
const flattenArray = (params) => {
  for (const sm of params) {
    if (Array.isArray(sm)) {
      flattenArray(sm)
    } else {
      newArray.push(sm);
    }
  }
  return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every function has to "return" something, and that's result value of your function!

Imagine a sum function without a return value!

```js
const noreturn_sum = (a, b) => {
  a + b
}
```

if you don't return something, your function returns `undefined` implicitly.

so if you gonna print the result of `noreturn_sum`, you will get:

```js
console.log(noreturn_sum(1, 2))

>> undefined
```

---

This is true even in your example, let me explain : (may I cleanup your code a little bit?)

```js
let newArray2 = []

const flatenArray2 = (params) => {
  // PART 1 ---------
  params.map((sm) => {
    if(Array.isArray(sm)) {
      flatenArray(sm) // PART 1.map.fn ---------
    }
    newArray2.push(sm);
  })
  // END PART 1 ---------

  // PART 2 ---------
  return newArray2
  // END PART 2 ---------
}

console.log(flatenArray2(multiArray))
```

A. your function for each parameter does this:

1. checks if it's an array:

true => call the function again to reach to a non-array value

false [it's a value] => add it to `newArray2`

2. then returns `undefined`

B. then your whole `params.map(...` returns an array of `undefined`, because your function inside map (that I explained it in (1.) and (2.) returns `undefined`

C. you return `newArray2` at the end of the function.

note that your `flatenArray2` function always return the `newArray2` but inside "PART 1.map.fn" you "discard" it (or you "ignore" it in other words)

but in the last experssion `console.log(flatenArray2(multiArray))` you gave the returned value to the `console.log` function.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but this seems to dance around the main issues in a way that Bergi's answer doesn't.  That one strikes right at the   Neither of these answers goes further to discuss the problem with the global `newArray`, but perhaps that's ok for beginner code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I was thinking of that, but thought it would de-emphasise the main point. I would then have to suggest using nested functions, or `flatMap`, at which point one could just call `flat`…

Comment: @Bergi: Right, and you answered the question asked.  If the question were simply how to flatten a nested array, it would have ideally been closed as a duplicate anyway.  But you answered the "why does variant A work and not B?" question well, with the addition of a better version of the same style.  This answer is not horrible, but it misses some of the finer points.  (BTW, there's obviously a simple recursive answer as well as `flatMap` ... unless recursion is what you meant by "nested functions".)

Answer (score 0):

When you do not use the result, either by assigning, passing or returning, you are solely relying on the side effects on the function.

Eg. in your `flatenArray` if you pass it a `[[1]]` `sm` will be `[1]`, thus the if test is `true` and it will recurse with `[1]`. It will then fail on the test because `1` is not an array and push `1` to `newArray`. It then returns `newArray` which is then instantly returned and no more of that function is used in that round. You never use the resulting array from `map` since you are never ever returning this so one could question why you didn't use `forEach` instead to enforce that it is just for side effects (mutating `newArray`). If you were to remove `return` it will continue down and do `newArray.push(sm)` even though it is an array Thus you would get both flattened results and unflattened results in the result array mixed and doubled up. This could be prevented by having the last statement in an `else` so that the function either did the array thing or the element thing.

The `flatenArray2` doesn't recurse as it uses `flatenArray` that populates `newArray` and not `newArray2` so it will only make a shallow copy of the original array due to the flattened elements being added to `newArray` and the unflattened elements being added to `newArray2` which is the only result that is returned.

If you were to call any function twice you will get the results of the previous runs in the second.

This is how I would have made it to prevent it from keeping results from previous rounds and actually using the results returned:

```js
const multiArray = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5]]], 6, [7, 8, 9, [10]]];

const flattenPure = (arr) => {
  const helper = (acc, e) => 
    Array.isArray(e) 
    ? e.reduce(helper, acc) // reduce the array e with acc as accumulator
    : [...acc, e];          // make a new array with elements from acc and the element e
    
  return arr.reduce(helper, []); // start with an empty accumulator
}

console.log("Once Pure", flattenPure(multiArray));
console.log("Twice Pure", flattenPure(multiArray));
```

Using `Array.proptype.push` makes a faster version, however then why not just use [Array.prototype.flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat))?

```js
const multiArray = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5]]], 6, [7, 8, 9, [10]]];

const flattenSide = (arr) => {
    let res = []; // this is new every time flatten is called
    const helper = (e) => {
        if (Array.isArray(e)) {
            e.forEach(helper); // indirect recurse for each element
        } else {
            res.push(e);
        }
        // hidden return undefined here
    };
    helper(arr); // flatten arr with result in res
    return res;  // return result
}

console.log("Once Side", flattenSide(multiArray));
console.log("Twice Side", flattenSide(multiArray));
```